# Handling priority with events from extenal libraries in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, remodal

I'm using [Remodal](http://vodkabears.github.io/remodal/) Javascript lib to handle with modal windows.
The point is that the library has handlers for custom events, e.g. the following javascript

```
$(document).on('opening', '.remodal', function (e) {
   console.log('opening');
});
```

will be triggered when a modal window is open by clicking on another DOM element.

```
<a data-remodal-target="modal-window-id" id="trigger">CLICK ME TO OPEN MODAL</a>

<div class="remodal data-remodal-id="modal-window-id>MODAL CONTENT</div>
```

Now, If I add in a javascript file also the following call to a click event

```
$(document).on('click', '#trigger', function (e) {
   console.log('trigger clicked');
});
```

regardless of the position of the previous script (i.e. before or after the other), I see that the `opening` event is fired before. I know, in Javascript there is not really a guarantee of event execution, apart from some exeptions or when using jQuery (e.g. attaching the listeners in the proper sequence).

Now, how can I manage to execute `click` before `opening`? It occurs before, but somehow there should be another `click` listener attached to that anchor that is executed before.

Any idea?

Comment: If what you're really after is a way to force execution of code in opening handler to run after click handler, you can always use setTimeout("console.log('opening');",100); to delay

Comment: @mjw thanks for the feedback. Does not seem a reliable solution. What happens if the first click takes more than 100ms?

Comment: If it takes longer than 100ms to console.log idk what to tell you ;)

Comment: No, I mean, what if the function executed by the click events takes more than 100ms

Comment: @mjw anyway the solution works, I'm not 100% sure that it is reliable, but works. So, maybe you can post a full answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're really after is a way to force execution of code in opening handler to run after click handler, you can always use setTimeout:

```
setTimeout("console.log('opening');",100);
```